# Is this "Remove child before washing" clothes label real?

Tags: consumer-products, photography, clothing

The image below went somewhat viral:

[image: Remove child before washing]

It shows a clothes label with the text "Remove child before washing".

Is this an actual clothes label of an actual commercially available piece of clothing?  Or is it a joke — either through digital photo editing, or by producing a fake clothes label?

Comment: I traced it back to these two twitter posts: https://twitter.com/asiandiver/status/480322632098013184
https://twitter.com/svmarcela/status/479502252043169792
and this image http://hugelol.com/lol/295342

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The label is real.

It is a joke on behalf of the manufacturer, the Norwegian company "Ugly Children's Clothing"

(They now seem to be trading as [Marius Kids](http://mariuskids.no/oss-page/); the history/relationship was too convoluted for Google Translate to adequately explain.)

From a comment by [Bent](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/31916/bent) it seems:

: As for the story going from Ugly Childrens Clothing (UCC) to Marius Kids, your link states that when UCC closed in 2015 the remaining stock and the rights to the Marius pattern was bought by the founders of Marius Kids (2 women) who had previously in many years worked with childrens clothing. They were joined by one female employee from UCC. It was especially the need for good looking clothes for little boys that drives the founders, as they both have sons.

Evidence that it hasn't been faked in Photoshop comes from the various different sources of different clothes with different washing instructions, but the same joke:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Hat tip to @adam-phelps for two of those images.

Evidence that the manufacturer is Marius Kids/Ugly Children's Clothing comes from:

- [this review](http://daddyforever.com/2013/09/12/parka-t-shirt/)

> Ugly Children’s Clothing sent me two items for review [...] The shirt even includes washing instructions: wash inside out, remove child before washing. Funny, right?

- Tags on this [Instagram photo](http://instidy.com/robinskeie/p/877428374124422620_216415568)
- Tags on this [Instagram photo](http://www.online-instagram.com/media/895742409024371777_18342462)
- The designs that appear in the photos are consistent with a common pattern on Marius Kids clothing. For example, the first image is consistent with this picture from the [Marius Kids facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/mariuskids/photos/pb.177137160932.-2207520000.1446247363./10152966937675933/?type=3&theater):

[image]

Comment: As for the story going from Ugly Childrens Clothing (UCC) to Marius Kids, your link states that when UCC closed in 2015 the remaining stock and the rights to the Marius pattern was bought by the founders of Marius Kids (2 women) who had previously in many years worked with childrens clothing. They were joined by one female employee from UCC. It was especially the need for good looking clothes for little boys that drives the founders, as they both have sons.

Comment: If you zoom in a lot on that last picture (the pink onesie from their FB page), you can see that the second to last line on the lower tag says "Remove Child / Do not tumble dry".